# Internal Combustion Engines

Tags: electrical-engineering

I need to know the typical energy balance of an IC engine and where this energy goes, but I am unsure what exactly they are asking? Engines are not my main strengths, so I could do with as much as help as possible and as simple as it can be please? I tried researching this but everything I read was very complex and I didnt really grasp it. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a very simplistic view:

- Energy comes into the system in the form of chemical potential energy (gasoline)
- Energy leaves the system through mechanical work of the crank shaft
- Energy leaves the system through heat from the cooling of the engine
- Energy leaves the system through heat of the exhaust

You probably want to neglect things like the electrical system, including spark plugs alternator, etc.

If you want to quantify these, you'll need to look at:

- The difference incoming and outgoing weighted sums of enthalpy of formation for the gas air intake and exhaust
- The power of the engine
- The difference in temperature between the incoming and outgoing radiator fluid along with the specific heat of the fluid and flow rate.
- The difference in temperature between the incoming air and outgoing exhaust along with the specific heat of air and flow rate.

(Also as a rough estimate, I've heard that the energy source happens to split roughly evenly into the energy drains I've listed. However, I have no evidence for this.)

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of energy either goes into motion, or heat. The remainder goes into sound and mechanical degradation of the car components. [Efficiencies if IC engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine#Energy_efficiency), even running in their optimum region, can vary considerably. However, [Diesel is generally most efficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine) reaching approximately 50% of fuel energy into motion.